# how can I use dependent dropdown lists in php bootstrap modal?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, modal-dialog

I want to implement the dropdown lists in bootstrap modal.
I have already a demo code but I don't know how to implement it in the bootstrap modal.

In The bootstrap modal form will be open with 2 dependent dropdowns and after submitting the values will be saved to database.

Thanks a lot in advance.

**index.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP - dependent dropdown list</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://demo.itsolutionstuff.com/plugin/bootstrap-3.min.css">
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Select State and get bellow Related City</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Select State:</label>
                <select name="state" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">--- Select State ---</option>


                    <?php
                        require('db_config.php');
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM demo_state"; 
                        $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                            echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";
                        }
                    ?>


                </select>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Select City:</label>
                <select name="city" class="form-control" style="width:350px">
                </select>
            </div>


      </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
$( "select[name='state']" ).change(function () {
    var stateID = $(this).val();


    if(stateID) {


        $.ajax({
            url: "ajaxpro.php",
            dataType: 'Json',
            data: {'id':stateID},
            success: function(data) {
                $('select[name="city"]').empty();
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    $('select[name="city"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                });
            }
        });


    }else{
        $('select[name="city"]').empty();
    }
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

**ajaxpro.php**

```
<?php


   require('db_config.php');


   $sql = "SELECT * FROM demo_cities
         WHERE state_id LIKE '%".$_GET['id']."%'"; 


   $result = $mysqli->query($sql);


   $json = [];
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $json[$row['id']] = $row['name'];
   }


   echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

[image: the output of dependent dropdownlists, I want to open and submit these dropdowns in bootstrap modal]

please help me.. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

**index.php**

```
<?php 
    include("db/db.php");
    $select_country = "SELECT country_id,country_name from country";
    $result_country = mysqli_query($con,$select_country);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ADDRESS FORM</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on("click","#reg",function(){
            $(".modal-title").html("Registration Form");
            $("#myModal").modal({backdrop: "static", keyboard: false});
        });
        $(document).on("click","#adddata",function(e){
            var state = parseInt($("#selectstate").val());
            var country = parseInt($("#selectcountry").val());
            console.log(state+country);
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'insert_all.php?action=ins_std',
                data : {'state': state,'country' : country},
                dataType : "JSON",
                success:function(feedback){
                    if(feedback=="yes"){
                        $(".alert2").html("<b style='color:green;'>Recored Successfully Added </b>");
                        $("#std-form")[0].reset();
                        $("#myModal").modal('hide');
                        $(".has-error").removeClass("has-error");
                        $(".alert2").show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
                    } else{
                        $("#alert").show();
                        $(".alert1").html("<b style='color:red;'> Cant Add Recored </b>");
                        $(".alert1").show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
                    }   
                }
            });
        });
        $(document).on("change","#selectcountry",function(){
        var c_id = parseInt($("#selectcountry").val());
        console.log(c_id);
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'get_asc.php',
            data : {'country_id' : c_id},
            success : function(feedback)
            {
                $("#selectstate").html(feedback);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" id="btn_close">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"></h4><div class="alert1" id="alert"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form name="add" method="post" id="std-form">
                        <div class="form-group item-required" id="selectcountryerror">
                          <label for="country">Country</label>
                          <select id="selectcountry" name="selectcountry" class="form-control input-value">
                            <option value="">Select Country</option>
                        <?php foreach ($result_country as $country) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $country["country_id"]?>"><?php echo $country["country_name"]?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group item-required" id="selectstateerror">
                        <label for="state">State</label>
                        <select id="selectstate" name="selectstate" class="form-control input-value">
                            <option value="">Select State</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" id="areaerror">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="adddata" >Add Data</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="savedata" data-dismiss="">Save Data</button><br>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btnclose" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <center>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" id="reg" >Click Here For Registration Form</button>
    </center>
</div>
</body>
```

**get_asc.php**

```
 **insert/select page**
<?php
    include("db/db.php"); 
    if(isset($_POST['country_id']))
    {
        $select_state = "SELECT state_id,c_id,state_name from state where c_id = '".$_POST['country_id']."' ";
        $result_state = mysqli_query($con,$select_state);
?>
    <option value="">Select State</option>
<?php
    foreach($result_state as $state) {
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $state["state_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $state["state_name"]; ?></option>
<?php
        }
    }

    elseif($_REQUEST['action']=="ins_std") 
    {
        $country = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['country']);
        $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['state']);
        $insert_std = "INSERT into student (s_id,c_id) values ('".$state."','".$country."')";
        $res_std=mysqli_query($con,$insert_std);
        if($res_std){
            echo json_encode("yes");
        }else{
            echo json_encode("fail");
        }
    }
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just add bootstrap modal instead of `panel` and a button for open that modal and add your form in a modal body.
Your code of `index.php` looks like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP - dependent dropdown list</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Modal Example</h2>
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Select State and get bellow Related City</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="title">Select State:</label>
                  <select name="state" class="form-control">
                      <option value="">--- Select State ---</option>
                      <?php
                        require('db_config.php');
                          $sql = "SELECT * FROM demo_state"; 
                          $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
                          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                              echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";
                          }
                      ?>
                  </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="title">Select City:</label>
                  <select name="city" class="form-control" style="width:350px">
                  </select>
              </div>
              <button type="submit">submit</button>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>


    <script>
      $( "select[name='state']" ).change(function () {
          var stateID = $(this).val();
          if(stateID) {
              $.ajax({
                  url: "ajaxpro.php",
                  dataType: 'Json',
                  data: {'id':stateID},
                  success: function(data) {
                      $('select[name="city"]').empty();
                      $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                          $('select[name="city"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                      });
                  }
              });
          }else{
              $('select[name="city"]').empty();
          }
      });
    </script>


  </div>

</body>
</html>
```